# Python Prints List Object [tkinter.StringVar object at 0x01FEAD50], But Not Items in List *Tkinter*

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI that will be able to monitor the integrity of files using their MD5 hashes (the actual monitoring of updates log can be in the command prompt).

I got the initial command line program to work perfectly, but am having an issue when converting it to a GUI based version using `tkinter`.

I use the GUI to create a list of files that I want to monitor in the '`addFiles`' function, but when I try to pass that list to the '`checkForIntegrity`' function (or print the list with my test `print(listOfFiles)` code in that function), all I get is `[tkinter.StringVar object at 0x01FEAD50]`, but do not get the actual list.

I have searched far and wide for an answer and have tried using various implementations of '`listOfFiles.get()`' in different locations but have had no success.

I have no idea why I only get the actual list object but no listed items, my code is below.

Thank you in advance everyone.

edit: Just to be clear, my 'GUI()' function creates a window that asks how many files the user would like to monitor and passes that to the 'addFiles()' function which allows input for the amount of files they specify. I need to be able to pass the files they specify in that GUI to the program via a list. Thanks again.

```
import hashlib
import time
from tkinter import *

def main():  
    GUI()

def GUI():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Integrity Checker")
    frame1 = Frame(window)
    frame1.pack()
    label1 = Label(frame1, text = "***Proof Of Concept Program That Monitors the Integriry of Files***")
    label1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    frame2 = Frame(window)
    frame2.pack()
    getNumberOfFiles = Label(frame2, text = "Insert Number of Files You Would Like to Check: ")
    getNumberOfFiles.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    numberOfFiles = IntVar()
    NumberOfFilesOption = Entry(frame2, textvariable = numberOfFiles)
    NumberOfFilesOption.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    button = Button(frame2, text = "OK", command = lambda : addFiles(numberOfFiles))
    button.grid(row = 2, column = 3)


    window.mainloop()


def addFiles(numberOfFiles):

    listOfFiles = []    

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Add Files")
    frame1 = Frame(window)
    frame1.pack()
    label1 = Label(frame1, text = "***Select The Files You Want To Monitor***")
    label1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


    for i in range (numberOfFiles.get()):
        AddFile = Label(frame1, text = "Add File:")
        AddFile.grid(row = (i + 3), column = 1)
        FileName = StringVar()
        FileNameOption = Entry(frame1, textvariable = FileName)
        FileNameOption.grid(row = (i + 3), column = 2)
        button = Button(frame1, text = "OK", command = lambda : listOfFiles.append(FileName))
        button.grid(row = (i + 3), column = 3)
    button2 = Button(frame1, text = "Done", command = lambda : checkforINTEGRITY(numberOfFiles, listOfFiles))
    button2.grid(row = (i + 4), column = 2)

    window.mainloop()


def checkforINTEGRITY(numberOfFiles, listOfFiles):

    #Number = numberOfFiles.get()
    #listOfFiles = []
    #count = 0
    #numberOfFiles = eval(input("How many files would you like to monitor?: "))
    #while count < Number:
     #   filename = input("Enter the name of the file you would like to check: ")
     #   count += 1
     #   listOfFiles.append(filename)

    print(listOfFiles)
    i = 0
    originalList = []
    for file in listOfFiles:
        original_md5 = hashlib.md5(open(listOfFiles[i],'rb').read()).hexdigest()
        originalList.append(original_md5)        
        i += 1
    print(originalList)

    while True:

        i = 0
        while i < Number:
            md5_returned = hashlib.md5(open(listOfFiles[i],'rb').read()).hexdigest()

            print(md5_returned)

            if originalList[i] == md5_returned:
                print("The file", listOfFiles[i], "has not changed")
            else:
                print("The file", listOfFiles[i], "has been modified!")
            i += 1

        time.sleep(5)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to call the `get` method on `FileNameOption`:

```
button = Button(frame1, text = "OK", command = lambda : listOfFiles.append(FileNameOption.get()))
```

With this change I was able to get a list of strings in `listOfFiles`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved everything. My list only appends the name of one file in each index for however many files you add, but that's today's project. Thanks again.